# WordPress problem with fatal error

Tags: fatal-error

After installing new plugin on my site, it shows me this statement:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_themes() in /home/poduszko/domains/poduszkowiec.com.pl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/bws_menu/bws_include.php on line 57

I'm totally new in this stuff, so please don't hate me so much. I'm worried that I couldn't make it only by myself. Does anyone could explain me how to fix this?

It's WordPress v 3.2.1.

Comment: I will start updating WordPress.

Comment: 3.2.1 is very very old, most plugins assume the latest version or a more recent version. The current version right now is v4.9.7

Comment: If I haven't made any backup yet, how can I make it in current form? Or should I update WP at first?

Answer (score 4):

The [Google Captcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/) plugin that you are using requires at least WP version 3.9, which might be why you are getting the error.

The WP 3.2.1 is quite an old version and there have been a few big security updates since, so you should update it anyway. Don't forget to take a backup of your site first.

Comment: I don't really know how to make both of those things, May you tell me what should I do? I haven't done such things in the past, apologize in advnace for my lack of knowledge

Comment: To fully backup your WordPress site you will need to backup your WP installation files as well as your WP database. You can backup the WP files by simply downloading them to your computer (e.g. via an FTP client like FileZilla). Backing up your DB will depend on your control panel, e.g if you are using cPanel or have access to phpMyAdmin you can just export it via there (and if anything goes wrong import it back). You can read more about backing up WordPress in the WP Codex[link](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups#Backing_Up_Your_WordPress_Site) or try looking up questions here.